# "cannot find install snap firefox at revision 2277: missing file /snap/firefox/2277/meta/snap.yaml"

Tags: firefox

[image]

This just started happening tonight. When I try to start firefox, the cursor spins around for a moment and then nothing. Firefox never starts up and its not found anywhere in htop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to uninstall snapd/snap and reinstall them.  Here the exact steps I followed to resolve this issue:

1. List all the snaps installed using `snap list`
2. Remove each snap that I had installed using `sudo snap remove --purge <packageName>` For example, `sudo snap remove --purge firefox` Repeat for each snap I had installed.
3. Remove the remaining snaps using `sudo snap remove --purge <packageName>`. You will have to remove all others before being able to remove snapd. I removed in the following order:
   *gtk-common-themes, gnome-3-28-1804, gnome-3-38-2004, core18, core20, bare, snapd*. Note you may have different ones and more or less. Finally, run `snap list` to make sure you got them all. The output will state something like,

> No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.

4. `sudo apt purge snapd` to remove snapd from Ubuntu.
5. Remove snap related directories. (Be careful running this command, you should not have any import data in those directories. If not sure you can always create a backup copy at a different location prior to entering the following commands.)

   > ```
   > sudo rm -rf ~/snap
   >
   > sudo rm -rf /snap
   >
   > sudo rm -rf /var/snap
   >
   > sudo rm -rf /var/lib/snapd
   > ```
6. Restart Ubuntu
7. `sudo apt install firefox` and reinstall any other packages that you want.